# How do you pass multiple arguments in a function for C programming

Tags: c, function

I am trying to figure out how to pass two arguments into my function outside my main. More specifically, I am writing a program that asks a user to input a string of characters and then the amount of shifts they want (to do a circular shift of the characters). I am using the following to get what the user inputs for the string into the function, but I do not know how to get what they enter for the number of shifts into the function as well:

```
char* circularArr(char[]);

int main(void){

//do stuff

}

//function:

char* circularArr(char str[]){

static int i=0;
static char cshift[MAXSIZE];

if(*str){
    printf("%c\n", *(str+1));
     circularArr(str+1);
     cshift[i++] = shifts;
}

return cshift;
}
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like, how do you pass more than one argument?  Something like `char * circularArr(char str[], int someNumber)` ?

Comment: why not try two arguments seperated by comma. (char str[], int no_of_shifts)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it as a second parameter:

```
char* circularArr(char[] myString, int shiftSize );
```